# HC08 Bootloader

Tags: bootloader, firmware

Can someone explain the basic process of flashing a bootloader to an *HC08* based MCU? Specifically the **MC908QB8**.

If I understand it correctly, the firmware can be updated via serial while the chip is in-circuit but there is a separate process for flashing the bootloader?

Comment: Most MCU's have JTAG, serial, external memory and a few other ways of booting. The best place to check is the (usually long) datasheets.

Comment: Looking at page 196 of the datasheet suggests that I need to build a basic programming circuit to enable "Monitor Mode" before I can successfully flash it? - https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC68HC908QB8.pdf